# Including leaflet with angular2.2.0

Tags: angular, leaflet

I was using leaflet with Angular2.0.0 successfully but when I moved to Angular2.2.0, I get

app/map.service.ts(4,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'leaflet'.

systemjs.config.js includes

`map: { 
    'leaflet':  'node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js'
}`

and package.json 
`"dependencies": { "leaflet": "^0.7.7" }`

but as soon as I want to include in my map.service.ts file

`import {Map} from 'leaflet';`

I get the error.  Please help.

Comment: Do you have installed the @types/leaflet?
It seems isn't a problem with the systemjs, but with the typescript compiler that can't find this module: "error TS2307"
You can see how the TypeScript module resolution works here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Answer (score 0):

AngularCli move from SystemJS to Webpack.
And if you want to use libs like leaflet you need provide it in angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/leaflet/dist/css/lib_name.css"
    "styles.scss"
  ],
"scripts": [
        "./assets/scripts/sw.js",
        "../node_modules/leaflet/dist/js/lib_name.js"
      ],
```

Also you need to provide a declaration of your 3tyLibs in src/typing.d.ts
for example:

```
declare module L; //then you can use L (lealflet object) in your services and component
```